# Malliavin calculus w.r.t $G$-Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I wonder if it is possible to define a Malliavin calculus w.r.t  $G$-Brownian motion defined on a Sublinear Expectation Space available on this [link](http://www.oxford-man.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/events/2010-Book-GBM-1002.4546v1.pdf).
G–Brownian motion has a very rich and interesting new structure which nontrivially
generalizes the classical one. Many interesting, attractive and challenging problems are also automatically provided within this new framework.

But Google does not provide any link on the Malliavin calculus in this new area.

Nevertheless all classical notions of stochastic calculus have been defined: Itô fomula, Girsanov theorem, white noise process, fractional Brownian motion etc..., except Malliavin calculus.

1. What problems hinder this concept?
2. Is for sublinearity of $G$-expectation which does not establish the
   integration by part formula? 
   Any help is welcome.
   Thank's

Comment: http://www.mn.uio.no/math/english/research/groups/stochastic-analysis/events/seminar_20120328.html

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker: Thank you very much for the link. However there are only the title. The file is not available on the net.